# Snippets (based on MIT licence) from snippets services

Tags: source-code, mit-license, code-snippets

I have question about MIT licence code sources

1. Can I publish code snippets [MIT licence] from site like bootsnipp to my blog?
2. Do I have to include source link to site where I have found that snippet (it has been published there first and its MIT)? or not?

Comment: ...have you read the license?

Comment: Yeah.. i have read MIT license the first answer is rhetorical and clear "yes".. but for second am not sure.. that's why i ask

Answer (score 4):

The [MIT license](http://opensource.org/licenses/MIT) states:

> Permission is hereby granted ... to deal in the Software without restriction, including without limitation the rights to use, copy, modify, merge, publish,
>   distribute, sublicense, and/or sell copies of the Software ... subject to
>   the following conditions:
>
> The above copyright notice and this permission notice shall be
>   included in all copies or substantial portions of the Software.

There's only one condition you are subject to: include the copyright notice. Therefore, the answers to your questions are:

1) Yes, you can copy and publish them as long as you include the copyright notice.

2) No, you are not *required* to link to where you found it. But it's still a good idea to cite your sources even if the license doesn't require you to do so.